# Is it possible to save logging information from python project in a local variable?

Tags: python, json, logging

I am using logging for one project. As of now I am storing all of my logging information in a file create by a RotatingFileHandler. However, I was wondering if it were possible to save all of the logging information in a dictionary-like local variable on my machine ?

I want to do this because one of the requirements for this project is to not create any new files during the execution of the process.

Comment: Check out [Capturing Python Log Output In A Variable](http://alanwsmith.com/capturing-python-log-output-in-a-variable)

Comment: have you tried using MemoryHandler instance?

_MemoryHandler instances send messages to a buffer in memory, which is flushed whenever specific criteria are met._

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#useful-handlers

Comment: I have not tried using the MemoryHandler instance but it might work

Answer (score 3):

The content on this website helped me find the solution : http://alanwsmith.com/capturing-python-log-output-in-a-variable.
Here is an extract of the code used.

```
import logging
import io

### Create the logger
logger = logging.getLogger('basic_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

### Setup the console handler with a StringIO object
log_capture_string = io.StringIO()
ch = logging.StreamHandler(log_capture_string)
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

### Optionally add a formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

### Add the console handler to the logger
logger.addHandler(ch)


### Send log messages. 
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warn('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')


### Pull the contents back into a string and close the stream
log_contents = log_capture_string.getvalue()
log_capture_string.close()

### Output as lower case to prove it worked. 
print(log_contents.lower())
```

You add `log_capture_string` as argument to your `StreamHandler` and then you get your content from your `log_capture_string` StringIO